# Check if a value in one column in one dataframe is within the range between values in two columns in another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'chr':[1,1],'pos':[100, 200]})  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'chr':[1,1,2],'start':[90,110,90],'stop':[110,120,110]})
```

I want to make a new dataframe with info from both dataframes if:
the value in df1['chr'] is the same is df2['chr']
and
the value df['pos'] is between the values in df2['start'] and df['stop']

From the dataframe above the result should be:

```
chr  pos    start    stop  
1    100    90    110
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You could have multiple start and stop for a pos, which one do you want to use?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I want all start stop rows. The answers below selects all rows where pos is within range of start and stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
df = df1.merge(df2,on='chr',how='left')
df.loc[(df['pos'] >= df['start']) & (df['pos'] <= df['stop'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) followed by [`series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
m=df1.merge(df2,on='chr',how='left')
m.loc[m.pos.between(m.start,m.stop)]

   chr  pos  start  stop
0    1  100     90   110
```